# Multi-conditional fuction with unknown variables in R

Tags: r, function

Suppose I had created a data frame with the following format:

```
matriz<-matrix(1:12,3,4)
as.data.frame(matriz)
colnames(matriz)<-c("Object A","Object B","Var1","Var2")

 Object A Object B Var1 Var2
   1          4      7   10
   2          5      8   11
   3          6      9   12
```

Now, applying the following "function", I want the following result:

Function:

```
filter_and_add<-function(x,var1,var2,...) {
y<-data.frame()
id1<-colnames(x)[1]
id2<-colnames(x)[2]
var1<-c(var1)
var2<-c(var2)
y1<-melt(x,id=c(id1,id2),measure.vars=c(var1))
y2<-melt(x,id=c(id1,id2),measure.vars=c(var2))
y<-rbind(y1,y2,...)
y
}
```

Result:

```
 Object A Object B Variable Value 
   1          4      Var1     7
   2          5      Var1     8
   3          6      Var1     9
   1          4      Var2     10
   2          5      Var2     11
   3          6      Var2     12
   .          .      Varx     z
   .          .      Varx     z
   .          .      Varx     z
```

Obs.: I don't want, the var2 and forth to be necessary on the function "filter _and_add"

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df %>% 
    gather(Variable, Value, -ObjectA, -ObjectB) %>% 
    filter(Variable == 'Var1') # or filter(str_detect(Variable, 'Var1'))

  ObjectA ObjectB Variable Value
1       1       4     Var1     7
2       2       5     Var1     8
3       3       6     Var1     9
```

**Explanation:** 
1. `gather` convert data frame into long format. - sign in gather says to not select ObjectA and ObjectB to converting them to long format. 
2. `filter` is self explanatory.